# an algorithm to find the shortest path between two vertices whose weight is divided by 3?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

I am trying to think of an algorithm such that giving a graph $G(V,E)$, and a weight function $w\colon E \to \mathbb{N}_+$ (which means giving every edge in the graph a positive weight), and a source vertex $S$, the algorithm finds the shortest path between each $v \in V$ and $S$, such that the weight of the path is divided by 3 . (The weight of the path means the sum of all the weights of the edges that are on the path.)

In some solutions, I found that for this problem they built a new auxiliary graph which will "maintain the weight modulo 3" so that when we get from $S$ to any vertex we will be interested in the path that starts and ends with remainder 0 and this is through duplicating the graph to 3 copies which will allow switching between different copies.

I don’t understand how to build such a graph and how it is going to help me with this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an algorithm which returns the weight of a lightest path between all paths with a weight divided by three](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141042/find-an-algorithm-which-returns-the-weight-of-a-lightest-path-between-all-paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $G=(V,E,w)$ the auxiliary graph you want to build is $H=(V', E', w')$ where:

- $V' = V \times \{0,1,2\}$
- Given $(u,i), (v,j) \in V'$,  $( (u,i), (v,j) ) \in E'$ if and only if $(u,v) \in E$ and $i+w(u,v) \equiv j \pmod{3}$.
- For any $e' =( (u,i), (v,j) ) \in E'$, $w'(e') = w(u,v)$.

For any vertex $v \in V$, a shortest path $\pi'$ between $(S,0)$ and $(v, 0)$ in $H$ induces a path $\pi$ from $S$ to $v$ in $G$ that is shortest among those having length divisible by $3$. In details, let $\langle v'_0, v'_1, \dots, v'_k \rangle$ be the vertices traversed by $\pi'$, where $v'_j = (v_j, i_j)$. The path $\pi$ traverses the vertices $\langle v_0, v_1, \dots, v_k\rangle$, in order.

Comment: how can i prove this ? i understand the algorithm but how to actually prove it

Comment: Prove that given any path $\pi$ of length $3k$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, from $S$ to a generic vertex $v$ in $G$, there exists a path $\pi'$ of length $3k$ from $S$ to $(v, 0)$ in $H$. This implies that a shortest path in $H$ is not longer than the shortest path in $G$. Then prove that, given any path $\pi'$ from $S$ to a generic vertex of the form $(v,0)$ in $H$ you have that: (i) the length of $\pi'$ is a multiple of $3$, and (ii) there is a path $\pi$ in $G$ from $S$ to $v$ having the same length as $\pi'$. This shows that a shortest path in $H$ is not shorter than the shortest path in $G$..

Comment: ...and also provides a constructive way to find $\pi$ from $\pi'$. I actually already described how to find $\pi$ in my answer so you just have to prove (i) and that the lengths of $\pi$ and $\pi'$ coincide.

Comment: thank you so much !